# Dependent Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests

Alright, so I'm using the Microsoft Test Framework for testing and I need to somehow build dependent tests. Why you might say? Because one of the tests ensures that I can load data from the database and the others need to operate against that set -- making the round trips is something we don't want to do to keep the automated nature of the tests efficient.

I have been searching and just can't seem to find a way to do a couple of things:

1. Decorate the test methods so that they are seen as dependent.
2. Persist the set between tests.

What have I tried?

Well, regarding the decoration for dependent tests, not much because I can't seem to find an attribute that's built for that.

Regarding the persistence of the set, I've tried a private class variable and adding to the `Properties` of the test context. Both of those have resulted in the loss of the set between tests.

I hope that you can help me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you need is an `orderer test list`. You can create this in you test project under 'New Item...'. The ordered test list is a list with tests in a specified order that are executed in the same `context`.

By the way: Unit tests should test only the smallest unit in an application, not a huge set of operations. Because if one unit is not working correctly you can find easy wich one.

Answer (score 2):

Create your test separately and then use the [Ordered Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704%28v=vs.100%29) to run them in the order you want.

If any of the tests fails then the whole test is aborted and it considered failed:

[image]